Are Greens function infrared finite in QED?
Scattering amplitudes are infrared divergent in QED, but are Greens functions infrared finite or infrared divergent. e.g. Is the four-point function
$G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\langle\Omega|T \Big(\bar{\psi}(x_1)\bar{\psi}(x_2)\psi(x_3)\psi(x_4)\Big)|\Omega \rangle$
infrared divergent?
